# Expanding the "other devices" history in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, history

When I open the History in Chrome on my work computer after having spent the morning on my home computer, I'd expect to see a long list of recent tabs from the home machine as well. Instead, I see maybe a dozen. (Weirdly, I see a longer list from the Chrome on my phone.) Is there a way to make it show more of them?